# I am having trouble with the "Lore" tag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to spawn a chest in the game with a water bucket in it.
I have been able to accomplish this, but my lore is for some reason not being applied to the bucket.

Here is the command in which I am using:

`/setblock ~1 ~ ~ chest 0 replace {Items:[{id:water_bucket,Slot:13,Count:1}],Lore:["Just in case you fall! ;)"]}`

Can anyone make it so the lore is applied?

Comment: Is the lore applied when you get the same item with `/give`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lore tag be applied to the item, inside the display tag, inside a data tag

e.g. `/setblock ~1 ~ ~ chest 0 replace {Items:[{tag:{display:{Lore:["Just in case you fall! ;)"]}},id:water_bucket,Slot:13,Count:1}]}`

Comment: Hmm, that didn't fix it. And I have to include the quotes or else it will give me an error message. I might just rename the water bucket to what I want the lore to be instead. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Pingyoping This new edit should work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure lore has quotes, or is a string compound (`{text:"<Insert Text>", color:"<color>"}`).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags), the correct syntax for Lore is the below:

> `{display:{Name:"name here",color:,Lore:["lore here", "lore here"]}}`

The same page also states that `Lore` is used within `display` and uses a String value type.  If you want to use a different color for the lore text, you'll need to supply the hexadecimal value.  A converter can be found [here](https://www.webpagefx.com/web-design/hex-to-rgb/).

I think part of your issue is you include a `;` in what seems like an odd spot, and right after that you also have a `)` that doesn't seem to link up to a `(` anywhere.  Both of those characters however are part of the `Lore` text because of the quotations, and unless they need to be escape in some way, they should just be rendered as text.  But I think the main issue is you do not use `display` in anyway.